# Why this works different if I use functions parameters instead of fixed values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m begining with JQuery and Javascript and doing a parallax scroll exercise, a question arose to me.

- I was writing the value of a var in a `<p></p>` every time that user makes scroll.
- That value is the result of an operation between the value of the scroll position and another value.
- If I put this last value like a fixed number in the function, it works and the number changes every time I use the scroll bar, but if I put this value like a parameter in the function, the function only calculate the first movement of the scroll and put that result in the `<p></p>`.

These are the two codes:

1. Numbers in `<p></p>` changes every time i move the scroll

   ```
   $(window).on("scroll", parallax);    
   function parallax(){
   var scrollSize=$(window).scrollTop();
   var scrollParallax=Number(scrollSize*0.5);
   $("p").text(scrollParallax);
   }
   ```
2. Number in `<p></p>` doesn´t changes, shows only the first value of the var

   ```
   $(window).on("scroll", parallax(0.5));
   function parallax(medida){
   var scrollSize=$(window).scrollTop();
   var scrollParallax=Number(scrollSize*medida);
   $("p").text(scrollParallax);
   }
   ```

What is the difference?

Why is this happening?

Comment: In the first you're sending in a function, in the second the result of a function.

Answer (score 2):

This is because [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) is expecting a function name or function definition for the handler parameter.

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

On startup the Javascript is executing `parallax(0.5)` to find the function it needs to call. It doesn't find a function so it is now in an error state and the event will never fire.

See the difference in my snippet bellow.

- `function` uses `parallax` and works,
- `Function Result` uses `parallax(0.5)` and **doesn't work**

```js
$('#eventBtn').on("click", parallax);
$('#resBtn').on("click", parallax(0.5));
function parallax(medida){
alert('parallax ran' + medida)
$("p").text(new Date().getTime());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>
<button id="eventBtn" type="button">Function</button>
<button id="resBtn" type="button">Function Result</button>
```

Comment: ".on() is expecting a handler not an function". A function is exactly what it expects. There's no Javascript type called handler, it's a concept and not a type.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for spotting the badly worded sentance.  Hopefully it is clearer now.